# Suggest Opencart best configuration

Tags: php, nginx, mariadb, opencart, opencart-3

Currently I am using opencart 1.5.5.1 and MariaDB on my website. I want to upgrade my configuration. I am thinking for these listed below.

```
PHP 7.3 (Latest) 
Opencart 3.0.3.1 (Latest) 
Nginx 
MariaDB
```

Can anyone help to suggest, is this the best configuration or not? Is this configuration help to improve my website performance?

Comment: sad to say... Opencart 3.0.3.1 still have a  bugs. Maybe better to use version 3.0.2 and find  bug fixes on github.

Comment: Thank you! If I will use Opencart version 3.0.2 then is this configuration will help to improve my site performance?

Comment: How many product u have in your OpenCart store?

Comment: Approx 10,000 products i have on my OpenCart store.

Comment: There are problems with the compatibility of some module extensions too. +1 for 302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for some bugs to be cleared from OC 3.0.3.1 before going there.

PHP 7.2 (tested and working just fine) 
Opencart 2.3.0.2 (stable) or 3.0.2.0
Nginx 
MariaDB

I would also recommend using CDN such as Cloudflare. 
Also using the right theme and modules is sometimes more important than your OC version.

Dont forget to look at this [link](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=fixes) especially [this for OC 3](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=123&t=208222), and also OC Forum.

You can also research [LiteSpeed](https://www.litespeedtech.com/) server instead of Nginx - is has a proper OC module now and gives very promising results.